# Excel VBA - How to start output on specific row in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, let me thank you all in advance for your time in helping me on this.

It seems simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out. The code just lists all sheet names in between certain sheets. I have mixed and matched some code together that I researched online and everything is working but one. The last thing I need is to be able to output starting from a specific row.

Currently, the output starts on cell A2. How do I deem the code to output starting on a specific cell, such as cell A3?

My code below:

```
Sub Summary_All_Worksheets()
Dim i As Long
Dim Low As Long, High As Long, Skip As Long
Dim Newsh As Worksheet
Dim Basebook As Workbook

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set Basebook = ThisWorkbook
Set Newsh = Basebook.Worksheets("Client Test")
Newsh.Columns("a").ClearContents

Low = Basebook.Worksheets("front").Index
Middle = Basebook.Worksheets("P5GBack").Index
High = Basebook.Worksheets("back").Index

If High < Low Then
    i = Low
    Low = High
    High = i
End If

With Newsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)
    For i = Low + 1 To Middle - 1
     .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Basebook.Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i

    For i = Middle + 1 To High - 1
        .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Basebook.Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This section of your code determines where the cells will begin populating (I've added comments to your code):

```
 With Newsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) 'count all the rows in the sheet, and 
'make everything relative to that row, in column 1. (Basically, you're 
'selecting the very bottom cell in column A.)
 For i = Low + 1 To Middle - 1 
    .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Basebook.Worksheets(i).Name 'Move up 
'from that bottom-most cell until you find a cell with a value (like 
'you were pressing ctrl+up). Go down one row (this is the 'Offset(1,0)'
' part), and in that cell, enter the worksheet name. 
Next i
```

While this way is quite stable and avoids overwriting any data, if you wanted to be able to put into the code a new place to begin your list, you could do it like this (to start in cell E5):

```
NewSh.Cells(5,5).Activate 'start in E5 on NewSh
For i = Low + 1 To Middle - 1
    ActiveCell = Basebook.Worksheets(i).Name 'put the name in the active cell
    NewSh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= ActiveCell.Value & "!A1",      TextToDisplay:=ActiveCell.Value'
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 'activate the next cell down
Next i
```

There are other ways to do this as well, the best one is determined by your situation (and I hasten to add--make the changes above in BOTH of your `For` loops. ;-)

Comment: This will put the data on the ActiveSheet, which may or may not be the desired sheet (OP's code correctly avoids this pitfall).  Also there is no need to use the ActiveCell for this

Comment: Thank you all so much, it worked beautifully. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry guys, one more question. How would I hyperlink all the names of the sheet list above? Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear. Please mark my answer as accepted if you can. I added a line for hyperlinking in my original answer.